# IE and quirks mode with widget

Tags: internet-explorer, web, quirks-mode

I have a javascript widget that I wrote for other people to copy and paste on to their site.

I am having an issue where if they do not specify a doctype on their page my widget blows up since it's using quirks mode on their page.

Is there anyway from my externally included javascript file to make sure the browser does not go into quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use the XHTML5 doctype for the widget if it is embedded via an iframe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
    <!--...-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--...-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**References**

- [Benefits of Polyglot XHTML5](http://www.xmlplease.com/xhtml/xhtml5polyglot/)
- [XHTML5 XML Schema](https://github.com/stefangrunert/XHTML5-XML-Schema)
- [XHTML5: The Zenith of Markup Languages](http://www.lesliesikos.com/xhtml5-the-zenith-of-markup-languages/)
- [HTML5 vs XHTML5](http://www.standardista.com/html5-v-xhtml5/)